# PyProj issue in working with OSMnx package

Tags: python, anaconda, openstreetmap, osmnx, pyproj

I have recently installed the OSMnx package using Anaconda environment (python 3.10.2) based on the installation instruction provided [here](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable). Once I try to import the OSMnx package into Python environment, it shows the following notification:

```
C:\Users\Reza\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py:91: 
UserWarning: Valid PROJ data directory not found. Either set the path using the 
environmental variable PROJ_LIB or with `pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir`. 
warnings.warn(str(err))
```

I have tried several solutions suggested on the Internet, but none of them worked for me! Do you have any ideas for resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this could be a difficult problem to reproduce, and since you have tried many solutions but none have worked for you, I recommend running OSMnx using Docker, following these simple steps:

1. [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/).
2. Pull the Docker image of OSMnx: `docker pull gboeing/osmnx`.
3. Change the location to your work directory: `cd path/to/workdir`.
4. Go to the "Usage" section of [this page](https://hub.docker.com/r/gboeing/osmnx), and depending on your operating system and the way you want to run OSMnx, choose a command and run it.

Comment: Thanks Tedpac! but I am looking for other solutions other than Docker. Please share with me if you find a way out.